# MYSQL JOIN multiple tables, avoiding duplicate entries on duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to SELECT JOIN three table.
Two of them have unique entries but one may have multiple rows for the unique identifier from my main table.
I would like to get multiple rows in my query result if in table three are multiple entries but I would like to get only differing values und no duplicates from row before.
For a simple example it should look like this:

Table user:

```
+----------+-----------+--------------+
| user_id  | user_name | email        |
+----------+-----------+--------------+
| 1        | name1     | one@ex.tld   |
| 2        | name2     | two@ex.tld   |
| 3        | name3     | three@ex.tld |
+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Table info:

```
+----------+---------+--------+
| info_id  | user_id | info   |
+----------+---------+--------+
| 1        | 1       | text1  |
| 2        | 2       | text2  |
| 3        | 3       | text3  |
+----------+---------+--------+
```

Table address:

```
+------------+--------+----------------+
| address_id | user_id| address_field1 |
+------------+--------+----------------+
| 1          | 1      | City A         |
| 2          | 1      | City B         |
| 3          | 2      | City C         |
| 4          | 2      | City D         |
| 5          | 2      | City E         |
| 6          | 3      | City F         |
+------------+--------+----------------+
```

My actual query is: 
SELECT u.user_name, u.email, i.info, a.address_field1
FROM user u
INNER JOIN info i ON (u.user_id = i.user_id)
INNER JOIN address a ON (u.user_id = a.user_id);

^^I tried LEFT JOIN and JOIN as well without success.

Query result:

```
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------------+
| user_name | email        | info   | address_field1 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------------+
| name1     | one@ex.tld   | text1  | City A         |
| name1     | one@ex.tld   | text1  | City B         |
| name2     | two@ex.tld   | text2  | City C         |
| name2     | two@ex.tld   | text2  | City D         |
| name2     | two@ex.tld   | text2  | City E         |
| name3     | three@ex.tld | text3  | City F         |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------------+
```

Query result I try to achieve:

```
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------------+
| user_name | email        | info   | address_field1 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------------+
| name1     | one@ex.tld   | text1  | City A         |
|           |              |        | City B         |
| name2     | two@ex.tld   | text2  | City C         |
|           |              |        | City D         |
|           |              |        | City E         |
| name3     | three@ex.tld | text3  | City F         |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------------+
```

I know this is possible but I don't know how and I'm not sure what I should search for. Can someone put me in the right direct?

Comment: Don't do this in SQL. Such display issues are better solved in the app or Webpage that is retrieving the data.

Comment: I don't try to use this for a productive environment or to repeadetly display data. This is for an one time export of data sets of a deprecated system, which should be imported to a new system by a API. This API requires the achived format if more than one address sets are available for a user.

Comment: Okay. You are cross joining all user's infos with all user's addresses. Five infos and three addresses for a single user make fiveteen result rows. Your sample doesn't contain multiple infos per user. Can you please add a user #4 with two infos and two addresses and show us what this shall look like in the results?

Comment: Multiple entries are only available for address sets. All other data are unique per user_id. I decided to customize the API and convert multiple address rows to columns in the query result. It seems to be less extensive to do so.

Comment: Strange datamodel then. Column `info` should simply be a column in the user table. There seems to be no need for an `info` table at all.

Comment: This was only a simple model of my data set. Finally it contains 64 columns from 4 tables.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT in combination with GROUP BY does more or less you need. 
GROUP_CONCAT without SEPARATOR option will generate comma separated values

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet    

SELECT u.user_name, u.email, i.info, GROUP_CONCAT(address_field1) AS address_field1
FROM user u
INNER JOIN info i ON (u.user_id = i.user_id)
INNER JOIN address a ON (u.user_id = a.user_id)
GROUP BY u.user_name, u.email, i.info
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works like a charm for recap several entries of third table in a single entry. Unfortunatelly the API which should process the query can't handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to peruse through this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b04fd1/14/0) to further test this query and its output!

```
SELECT u.user_name, u.email, 
GROUP_CONCAT(info) AS info, 
GROUP_CONCAT(address_field1) AS address_field1
FROM user u
INNER JOIN info i ON (u.user_id = i.user_id)
INNER JOIN address a ON (u.user_id = a.user_id)
GROUP BY u.user_name ASC

| user_name |        email |              info |       address_field1 |
|-----------|--------------|-------------------|----------------------|
|     name1 |   one@ex.tld |       text1,text1 |        City A,City B |
|     name2 |   two@ex.tld | text2,text2,text2 | City C,City D,City E |
|     name3 | three@ex.tld |             text3 |               City F |
```

Thanks! 
Omar M.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works like a charm for recap several entries of third table in a single entry. Unfortunatelly the API which should process the query can't handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to customize the API and will store several address data like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| user_name | email        | info   | address_field1 | address_field2 | address_field3 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| name1     | one@ex.tld   | text1  | City A         | City B         |                |
| name2     | two@ex.tld   | text2  | City C         | City D         | City E         |
| name3     | three@ex.tld | text3  | City F         |                |                |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppressing repeated data is done easily with `LAG` or `ROW_NUMBER` in standard SQL, but MySQL doesn't feature either.

What you can do is look up the first address in the address table again:

```
select
  case when is_first then user_name end as user_name,
  case when is_first then email end as email,
  case when is_first then info end as info,
  address_field1
from
(
  select 
    u.user_name,
    u.email,
    i.info,
    a.address_field1,
    a.address_field1 = (select min(address_field1)
                        from address fa 
                        where fa.user_id = a.user_id) as is_first
  from user u 
  join info i on u.user_id = i.user_id
  join address a on u.user_id = a.user_id
) compared
order by user_name, email, info, address_field1;
```